# What is "Devputra Mara"?

Tags: theravada

Tripitaka talks of four kinds of Mara. It says that to begin with there were 3 attempt of mara to stop Buddha ...

1. First in Skandha mara (self view)
2. Then Klesh mara (Desire, hate and ill will)
3. Finally Mrityu mara ("now you going to die")

... and when all attempts failed, he appeared in person. May be that being Buddha talk of Devputta Mara. Devputta literally means 'son of God'!

The natures of the first three maras can be known or understood from the general meaning of their names; but what about the "Devputra Mara"?

How to identify him? What are its characteristics?

If the first three are 3 obstacle of evil forces, to stop one from achieving enlightenment or liberation, I am asking the fourth one!

Did Buddha said about the Devputra Mara in detail? Does he says about him and give caution to not to fall for his trap?

Comment: Further details on Mara: http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/ma/maara.htm

Answer (score 2):

Deva,

Devaputta means [Deva by birth](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka_en.html#kama), one with a lot of merits, enjoying pleasant things, your-kind's largest trap, here in the realm of internet, in union with Maras host.

[*Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, other world-binding trades, but for release from this wheel*]